# Can a datatype have only 2 values?Or only an n number of values?

Tags: java, class, variables, object

The question wont make too much sense let me explain.
I want for example a class

```
package code;

public class Person {

String Name; //a person has a name
SomeKindOfDatattype gender; //A person has a gender
//i want only 2 possible values of gender that is male or female
}
```

please explain briefly

Comment: You can add verification to your constructor/methods to ensure that only specific values are accepted. One other idea is to use an `enum`, which would allow you to define constants like `MALE` and `FEMALE`. You can find an `enum` tutorial here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Heraphrodites may have both genders.

Comment: OMG, **8** Answers for such simple question!!

Comment: @Yahya And everyones hunting for reputation. Just for fun id like to add a bounty of 500, just to see how they are killing each other ;D Haha, this will be funny!

Comment: Thank you every one. I'm a 12 year old trying to do java. You guys must be professional at this! I'm sorry if this question made you cringe. The enum worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a enum "Gender" which contains the values "Male" and "Female"
(Can be embedded to class)

```
public enum Gender{
   MALE, FEMALE
}
```

Can called by `Gender.MALE`

Answer (score 1):

**Enum class:**

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE;
}
```

**Person class:**

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private Gender gender;

    public Person(String name, Gender gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " is " + gender;
    }

}
```

**Main application:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person person = new Person("Charles", Gender.MALE);
        Person person1 = new Person("Kelly", Gender.FEMALE);

        System.out.println(person.toString());
        System.out.println(person1.toString());

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Charles is MALE
Kelly is FEMALE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use enum for this needs. Inside you can list all alowed values.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean male;
```

does only allow true or false.

Enums allow also the value `null` what is not realy a value.

Comment: Haters gonna hate

Answer (score 0):

You can use enum

```
 public enum Gender{ MALE,FEMALE }
```

data type will be gender

Answer (score 0):

If you have a type that must only have certain values, use an Enum :

```
enum Gender {
    MALE, 
    FEMALE
} 

public class Person {
    String Name;

    Gender gender;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enum` like below

```
enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE;
}
```

Here're some example of how to define and use it.
https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-enum-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can use an enumeration to do what you want.

Here, you are an example of how you can proceed.

`Person.java`

```
public class Person{

  private String name; 
  Gender gender; 

  public Person(String name, Gender gender){
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
 }

  public void display(){

    System.out.println("I'm " + name + " and I'm " + gender);
  }
}
```

`Gender.java`

```
public enum Gender{ Male, Female}
```

Here is the test code `TestPerson.java`

```
public class TestPerson{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    String name = "Alan";
    Gender gender = Gender.Male;
    Person p = new Person("Alan", gender);
    p.display();
  }
}
```

The code doesn't mention a package name. I assume that all the above code are in the same package. You can specify the package name as you want.